# jquery files conflicts how to detect?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Q:i have a general problem ,when i wanna to do some thing and i find the jquery file which can do exactly what i wanna to do . after a while i need another case and i find that another jquery file serve me and fix my problem .after i add set of jquery files i find conflicts among those files and some features does not work or work in awkward manner ..and when i try to find which file exactly the source for those problems i find myself in closed circle cannot modify this file or cannot delete this file or cannot find that file itself at all.sometimes the file like this:

`<script src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

cannot modify it.

the problem has many faces,and i cannot really know how to handle the whole matter from the beginning.

can any one give me instructions ,advices,notes, or explanation to prevent the problem from the beginning and how to fix it if it was happened.

Comment: What's the problem? What's the question?

Comment: the problem:when add set of jquery files ,, each group for a special thing after adding many files .. conflicts happens among those files..the question is there an organized way to prevent ,reduce this problem from the beginning and how to fix it easily if happens(as instructions)..

Answer (score 2):

Please have only one instance of Jquery Library.
The library has the capability to solve the issues.
Seperate instances or files will confuse the code.
I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks alot,,please what do u mean by one instance of Jquery Library?if u mean one include of the same file,, i do that already..

Comment: Kindly post the snippet that is causing the conflict to get more specific answer.

Comment: yeah i have one problem , like this when i add set of jquery files to show toast message boxes ,it works perfectly and then i add set of jquery to change the language (it works perfectly)alone ..when i add it to the project which has the first group of jquery files it works strangely and not what i want..but i post a general question so i can get general instructions to avoid this problem and fix it when i face it with myself..thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

If you point your browser at http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.js it will give you the JS file for you to download and save as your own copy. You can then change it as you want and link it in your website rather than use the one located at googlecode.com.

Answer (score 2):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

This link suggests few of the ways to avoid the jQuery conflict. Please check that as it could give you some more idea to resolve your problem.

Regards,
Lakxman Kumar C